# Stellar structure integration

Tags: astrophysics, stellar-physics

I have some issue regarding the stellar structure. I know analytically the equation of state, and I have been asked to build the structure of the star from these two equations

$\frac{dP}{dr}=-\frac{G m \rho}{r^2}$

$\frac{dm}{dr}=4 \pi r^2 \rho$

The problem is that I have been told to integrate over density, so I don't really know how to transform these equations in order to do that. Any help is welcome!

Comment: Ae you sure you haven't been told to use mass as the integrating variable?

Comment: Yes, I was explicitly told to use the density as the integration variable.

Comment: What do you know about the equation of state? Is it polytropic?

Comment: Not actually, it is an isothermal white dwarf with Sommerfeld corrections (arbitrary degeneracy) so it has to be integrated numerically.

Comment: So if it is isothermal then you have P = f(rho).

Comment: Yes, P is only a function of rho.

Answer (score 1):

If you have $ P = f(\rho)$, then $dP = f' d\rho$.

The equations of stellar structure become
$$\frac{dP}{d\rho} = f'$$
$$ \frac{dm}{d\rho} = - \frac{4\pi r^4 f'}{Gm} $$

For a more general equation of state, $P = f(T, \rho)$, then you would also need an equation for $dT/d\rho$, which you would get from the equation for energy transfer, either radiative diffusion or convective transport. Note, that even in a white dwarf, this is required in the outer $\sim 1$% (by mass) of the star, where degeneracy and isothermality cannot be assumed, and it may significantly alter the derived radius at a given mass, depending on the mass (negligible at higher masses) and interior temperature (negligible if $T< \sim 5\times 10^6$ K).